# how to close command connection with LINQ / EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

working with Azure and EF I get the error message:

```
 DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
```

It because my queries are nested:

```
foreach (Element s in ElementSet.All()) {
   if (somecondition) {  
     ElementSet.Add() 
   }
}
```

How can I load all the Elements from ElementSet and close the connection before I cycle through them with foreach?

P.S.: Apprently with SQL azure I can not set MARS in the connection string which would make the server accept multiple connections.

Answer (score 2):

MARS will not use multiple connections but it will allow multiple concurrent operations over single connection. [MARS was recently added to SQL Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/04/16/9997517.aspx) so you should definitely turn it on.

If you want to force EF to load all entities immediately call `ToList` in your query.

```
foreach (Element s in ElementSet.All().ToList()) {
   if (somecondition) {  
     ElementSet.Add() 
   }
}
```